In a CV for an epidemiology PhD application, should you put a summary at the top?
I am applying to PhDs in epidemiology in the US and would like to know the following:

should you put a summary on top of the CV? I see some examples have it and some do not.

if you had teaching roles, do you out things such as how the class was improved (not in an academic sense)?

should you put action words to describe or emphasize experiences on the CV?

how do you quantify experiences that are not quantifiable?


